# Why is 'kubectl' is not recognized as an internal or external command on WIndows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I edited env variables by pointing to kubectl and helm(after downloading them and storing into kube folder)

[image]

when I go for kubectl in cmd,I got
'kubectl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

Why?

Comment: Your `Path` does not seem to include the path that presumably contains `kubectl.exe` (i.e. C:\users\f85147\kube).

Comment: @StarCat how to add kube to Path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are not automatically used this way. The **only** variable that Cmd uses to find the location of commands is `PATH`, which is a list of directories (not files) that Cmd will look in.

Since `PATH` is already there in your environment variable window, just edit it to include the path to your `C:\users\f85147\kube` directory.

(On Windows, 'Path' and 'PATH' are the same thing.)

Other variables such as 'helm' aren't used to find commands. They're only used through explicit expansion when you type `%helm%` in Cmd, or `$helm` in Bash, or `$env:helm` in PowerShell (but never bare `helm`) and this expands to whatever value you've set in the variable.